# Change the OnClick event using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML anchor tag like

```
<a href="anchorid" onclick="callEvent(1)">
```

Here I call the Javascript function like

```
<script>
function callEvent(anchor) {
    alert("Anchor ID is - "+anchor);
    document.getElementById("anchorid").onClick = function () { callEvent(0) }; // BY using this code, update the onclick callEvent(0), like toggle
}
</script>
```

I wants to update the anchor tag like

```
<a href="anchorid" onclick="callEvent(0)">
```

When using this code, it is not updating as per my requirement.

```
 document.getElementById("anchorid").onClick = function () { callEvent(0) };
```

How do I get it to update?

Comment: PHP tag wasn't necessary here, i've removed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for using `document.getElementById("anchorid")..` you need to have `id` in your element, which you currently dont have, try doing:

```
//add id to your anchor
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="anchorid" onclick="return callEvent(1);">
    test
</a>
```

and js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callEvent(num) {
    alert("Anchor ID is - "+num);
    document.getElementById('anchorid').onclick = function () { callEvent(0) }; 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the toggle value in tag itself and then use.

```
<script>
function callEvent(val) {
    var val = document.getElementById("myId").getAttribute('data-val');
    alert(val);
    // toggle value
    val = val==1?0:1;
    document.getElementById("myId").setAttribute('data-val',val);
}
</script>
<a id="myId" data-val="0" onClick="callEvent()">Click</a>
```

here value is stored in `data-val` value so that is toggled in the callEvent function itself, so no need to rebind the event.

See [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/efFbR/)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
document.getElementById("anchorid").onclick
```

Better:

```
document.getElementById("anchorid").addEvenetListener('click', function(){

});
```

Comment: I am getting an error like this.. Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'addEvenetListener'

Comment: @user2688251 what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Tested: http://jsfiddle.net/Yca5W/

```
document.getElementById("anchorid").onclick =
    function () {
        alert("clicked");
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

try This:

```
var anchor= document.getElementById('anchorid');
  anchor.addEventListener('click', function() {
        callEvent(0);
    });
```

OR

```
$( "#anchorid" ).click(function() {
 callEvent(0);
});
```

if you only want changes passing parameter from 1 to 0 or vice verse then do this one:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="para" id="para" value="1" > 
    <a href="anchorid" onclick="callEvent($('#para').val())">



 $( "#anchorid" ).click(function() {
      if ($('#para').val()==1) {
        $('#para').val(0)
      } else {
        $('#para').val(1)
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only change parameter of calling function then you dont have to change complete event. You can do it like this:

***HTML***

```
<a id="anchorid" href="#">click me !</a>
```

***JS***

```
<script>
var anchor = 1;

document.getElementById("anchorid").onclick = function(){
    alert("Anchor ID is: " + anchor);
    anchor = anchor == 1 ? 0 : 1; //toggle 0 and 1
}
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it may solve your problem **demo** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymGH8/)

Add id="anchorid" to your anchor tag

When you click it next time it will callEvent by argument 0,

```
function callEvent(anchor) {
    alert("Anchor ID is - "+anchor);
    var ele =  document.getElementById("anchorid");
    ele.setAttribute("onclick","callEvent(0)");

}
```

It will update your link like you wanted

```
<a href="anchorid" id="anchorid" onclick="callEvent(0)">
```